# get row counts based on left joins of multiple mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

i have a query:

```
SELECT students.rollno, students.name, COUNT( sp.paperid ) AS papers
FROM sps sp
LEFT JOIN students ON students.studentid = sp.studentid
LEFT JOIN str st ON st.studentid = sp.studentid
LEFT JOIN iars ir ON ir.paperid = sp.paperid
LEFT JOIN attndata at ON at.iarsid = ir.id
LEFT JOIN hedata he ON he.iarsid = ir.id
LEFT JOIN assigndata asg ON asg.iarsid = ir.id
WHERE sp.studentid = at.studentid
AND sp.studentid = asg.studentid
AND sp.studentid = he.studentid
AND students.course =4
AND st.semesterid =1
AND st.sessionid =12
AND students.status = 'Regular'
GROUP BY students.rollno
```

i have a database where in i have students data namely their papers, personal data, attendance, assignment, examination data. i want to count the number of papers for which there is data in tables such as attndata i.e attendance, assigndata i.e assignement and hedata ie examination and sps table has the paperid(s) that a student is studying, str table relates to student semester. kindly help in getting the correct count of papers.

thanks.

Comment: What is the expected result and what are you getting?

Comment: expected result is the no of papers i.e papercoutn for which there is data in tables namely attndata, assigndata and hedata. i am getting the no of rows as correct but the paper count as distinct as 41, 39 etc whereas it should just come as 4 or less than 4 as no student is studying more than 4 papers.

Comment: Why dont you group by studentId?

Comment: @SashiKant its still not giving the desired result. the papercount is still coming as 31, 26, 32 etc please help a bit more